# Getting all images from a directory with an Axios call

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, permissions

I'm trying to create a simple gallery which works fine on localhost. I use the Axios library to get all the images from a single directory, I then map through results that come in and all the images get printed in a grid.

The same thing doesn't work on a real server, where I've uploaded my files to - the request returns 403 Forbidden error, which seems fair, because there'
s no index.html file in the images directory. I can access a specific image without any issues but I still would like to use an axios/fetch call to get all the images from a directory.

I've tried adding some htaccess rules but I'm not too familiar with these, so no luck. I've changed (for just a testing purpose, no worries!) every file's permission to 777, still no luck.

I'd appreciate any hints on how to handle this issue, as I'm not too familiar with servers and stuff.

The code for a call is simple, so I don't think there's an issue here. Maybe I need to include some headers?

```
  const getImages = () => {
  axios.get(helpers.galleryDir)
    .then(res => createImages(res.data, helpers.galleryDir))
    .catch(err => handleError(err));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar issues:

I've added a

```
Options +Indexes
```

to my .htaccess. Now the Axios call returned an HTML-like document that contained all images' names in  tags, so I've used some regex to get these names and then I mapped the images array as I normally would.